# With git, how do I remove a local copy of a remote branch? Or at least pull without merging?

Tags: git, branch, git-branch, branching-and-merging

Another developer has deleted and rebuilt a remote branch called "development" which I already have a checked out copy. He did this delete and rebuild to remove some cruft from it. Which is great.

But when I do a "git pull origin development" it keeps getting merge conflicts. Yet I don't want what I have in my copy. I want what is in origin only.

So how do I delete my local copy of it and pull it back down? Or at least pull without merging my local info into it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Grab the most up-to-date changes from the origin remote. This step is the “pull without merge” step you asked for in your question. `git pull` is the equivalent of `git fetch` followed by `git merge`.

```
$ git fetch origin
```

Get to a clean branch if necessary.

```
$ git stash
```

With a clean branch, switch to the development branch if you are not already there.

```
$ git checkout development
```

Finally, force your local development branch to point to the same commit as the one on origin.

```
$ git reset --hard origin/development
```

Always think twice before using `git reset --hard`, as with `rm -rf`. It is a sharp, useful tool, but it can destroy work if you are not careful.

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I was looking for. I was already working from a neutral state, so I didn't need the stash and I wasn't worried about losing any work. Awesome!

Answer (score 19):

To delete a local branch permanently, do:

```
git branch -D <branch-name>
```

Fetch changes from the remote repo but do not merge:

```
git fetch
```

Now create and checkout a local copy of the remote branch and track it:

```
git checkout -b development origin/development
```

git should tell you "Branch development set up to track remote branch development from origin", and that it's switched locally to the development branch.

Comment: Why would you update the master branch? (did you mean: ``git fetch``?)

Answer (score 1):

Found out this link with the 'prune' command:

https://opensource.com/article/22/8/delete-local-reference-remote-branch-git

It worked for me (even) in case of previously removed remote branch.

Comment: While the link may answer the question, it's best to include the relevant details in case it ever goes down.